# Generate Invoice PDF and send it monthly to all users architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Hello consider this image:

[image]

For explanation:

We want to send out Invoice PDFs to our customers monthly.
For this we have a cronjob that invokes a lambda 1x per month that fetches some data from the database. This lambda fetch lets say 500.000 user data. Each users needs to receive an invoice PDF

Because 1 lamda cannot generate 500k PDFs, i send this information to an SQS queue and i have a second lambda that generates this PDF.

I have few questions here:

1. I can only send up to 10 Messages at once. I cannot send it parallel at 500k users it would throw an timeout error i guess. I cannot send 10 messages sequencially, lamba is limited to 15 min
2. How much messages can a SQS store/buffer?
3. The invoice has an unique generated bill number. Therefore SQS should not be able to invoke multiple lambdas. I always need to check if the bill number already exist in the dynamoDB table

So, am i on the right track with this architecture, or am i completly wrong? Can you guys guide me a bit or show me some resources on the internet with a similar problem?

This data

Comment: Try to "loosely couple" things as much as possible. For example, does a single Lambda function need to generate the bill number, create the PDF _and_ send the email? What if you needed to re-send an invoice? Instead, consider breaking the task into separate steps, each linked via a different SQS queue so they can scale, queue and handle errors without impacting the entire flow. For example, what would happen if there is a problem sending emails -- every invoice would fail with the above design, but if it was broken into sub-tasks it could recover from failure.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yea. So you mean a way would be using step functions linked with SQS? Can a timeout happen or does this run until the job is done?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about implementing your workflow with a [Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html), where you can map the 500K entries one by one, and then orchestrate (and monitor) every step: questions 1 and 3 should be automatically resolved using a Step Function.

Here's a Step Function Workflow stub that:

0. It could be launched by an EventBridge rule, scheduled every month, or reacting on an S3 upload.
1. Parse the CSV (with a first Lambda) and returns it as a list
2. For every entry in the list, in a Map node:

   1. Enrich the payload getting some additional data on DynamoDB
   2. Create the invoice PDF, with a second Lambda
   3. Send the email, with a third Lambda

[image: Step Function Workflow stub]

Regarding question 2, from the [Amazon SQS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/?nc1=h_ls):

> **Q: How large can Amazon SQS message queues be?**
>
> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an unlimited number of
> messages. However, there is a quota of **120,000 for the number of
> inflight messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue**.
> Messages are inflight after they have been received from the queue by
> a consuming component, but have not yet been deleted from the queue.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your solution with step functions?

Comment: I added some explanation and a workflow stub in the answer